# C# JSON Rest client compatible with Net Framework 2.0

Tags: c#, json, rest, client

I'm loking for a simple library to make REST client calls using JSON and compatible with .Net framework 2.0.

Any thoughts?

Thank you

Answer (score -2):

You can use the [REST API asp.net](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/older-versions/build-restful-apis-with-aspnet-web-api) or web-api with the following code.

Install the [webapi client NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client/) package for this:

```
    public class YourClass
    {
        private const string URL = "http://your_path/ob.json";
        private string urlParameters = "?api_key=123";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(URL);

            // Add an Accept header for JSON format.
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            // List data response.
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(urlParameters).Result;  // Blocking call!
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                // handle if false
            }  
        }
    }
```

Another solution is [RESTsharp API](http://restsharp.org/)